# how to secure keys for API calls from android device to amazon services

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, api, security, key

so i am writing an app for android which will push some data over to Amazon S3 storage to be later read. I am using Amazons SDK to make my calls but this requires me to store the public and private keys within my app. Is there a way to secure them so they couldn't be extracted by reverse engineering? Is it even possible since i will be making direct calls from the device? Or is my only option to run a proxy server (on EC2) and pass my data through it?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1. Use HTTPS
Step 2. AES encrypt the keys in the application

Other than that, there's not much you can do, other than using a proxy server (option you mentioned)

Comment: And where do you put the AES key? Encrypt, rinse, repeat?

Comment: you can keep the key in the app, as long as you obfuscate your code you should be fine. The rest is overkill. One other option would be for the app to get the key dynamically from time to time, but this will only do the job slightly harder for "hackers"